# Добавить иконки в recyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Есть адаптер:

```
public class AdapterInfoContact extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    List<CountryCallingCode> valueContact = new ArrayList<>();
    Context context;
    RecyclerItemClick itemClick;

    public AdapterInfoContact(Context context, List<CountryCallingCode> features) {
        this.valueContact = features;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());

        switch (viewType) {
            case 0:
                View item_Header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_filter, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new ValHolder(item_Header);
                break;
        }
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
            case 0:
                ValHolder commentHolder = (ValHolder) holder;
                configureHeaderView(commentHolder, position);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void configureHeaderView(ValHolder valueHolder, int position) {
        if (valueContact.get(position).getInfo() != null) {
            if (position == 0) {
                valueHolder.mTvTitle.setText(valueContact.get(position).getInfo().getLogin());
            } else if (position == valueContact.size() - 1) {
                try {
                    if (valueContact.get(position).getInfo().getLocationCountry() != null && valueContact.get(position).getInfo().getLocationCountry().getValue() != null)
                        valueHolder.mTvTitle.setText(valueContact.get(position).getInfo().getLocationCountry().getValue() + "," + valueContact.get(position).getInfo().getLocationRegion().getValue());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    valueHolder.mTvTitle.setText(context.getString(R.string.country_tag));
                }
            }
        } else {
            valueHolder.mTvTitle.setText("(" + valueContact.get(position).getCountryCode() + ") " + valueContact.get(position).getNationalNumber());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return valueContact.size();
    }


    class ValHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        @BindView(R.id.title_filter)
        TextView mTvTitle;

        public ValHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (getAdapterPosition() == 0) {
                itemClick.itemLogin(valueContact.get(0).getInfo(), v);
            } else if (getAdapterPosition() == valueContact.size() - 1) {
                itemClick.itemMap(valueContact.get(getAdapterPosition()).getInfo(), v);
            } else {
                itemClick.itemContact(valueContact.get(getAdapterPosition()), v);
            }
        }
    }

    public interface RecyclerItemClick {
        void itemContact(CountryCallingCode code, View view);

        void itemLogin(Ad info, View view);

        void itemMap(Ad info, View view);
    }

    public void SetOnItemClickListener(final RecyclerItemClick mItemClickListener) {
        this.itemClick = mItemClickListener;
    }
}
```

Хотелось бы поместить картинки таким образом, чтоб получился список, НО уже с картинками). Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно сделать более безболезненно.

Код `item_filter`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_filter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:maxLines="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/value_filter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/title_filter"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/title_filter" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:background="@color/new_divider" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `В котором как Вы уже наверное успели заметить есть два RecyclerView.` – это как?

Comment: @post_zeew обновил вопрос

Answer (score 3):

Добавляете в **item_filter.xml** `ImageView` (не забывая указать атрибуты, которые будут определять его расположение):

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/my_image_view"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"/>
```

В `ValHolder` добавляете:

```
@BindView(R.id.my_image_view)
ImageView mMyImageView;
```

Добавляете в `Drawable` картинку `my_image`.

В методе `configureHeaderView(...)` устанавливаете эту картинку:

```
mMyImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_image);
```

**UPD.**

Если для каждого пункта нужна отдельная иконка, то лучше в `CountryCallingCode` добавить поле типа `int`, в котором будет хранится идентификатор ресурса (в данном случае, изображения) и сделать соответствующий геттер (например, `getImageId()`).

Тогда в `configureHeaderView(...)` делаете как-то так:

```
mMyImageView.setImageResource(valueContact.get(position).getImageId());
```

Comment: супер, только у меня для каждого элемента в списке своя иконка. Нужно дополнительно создать массив или как лучше присвоить   пункт , соответствующей иконке?

Comment: @Inkognito, Смотрите **UPD**.

Comment: извините, но надеюсь последнее уточнение, вы написали в котором будет храниться идентификатор ресурса - я в CountryCallingCode написал просто так private int ImageId; ну и получил геттер. Этого так понимаю недостаточно, т.к. он нигде не используется.

Comment: @Inkognito, Разумеется недостаточно. Вы передаете в адаптер (уже заполненную) коллекцию `List<CountryCallingCode> features`. Вот там, где Вы ее заполняете (хотя и не обязательно там), Вы должны установить значение поля `mImageId` соответствующим идентификатором.

Comment: не совсем понятно как *правильно* установить значение поля, так как выделяет красным ImageId в адаптере. И всё таки где её заполнять?( Извините, но действительно не очень получается.

Comment: @Inkognito, Можете заполнить эти поля перед тем как создаете инстанс адаптера. Еще раз: в класс `CountryCallingCode` добавляете поле `private int mImageId`, создаете для этого поля геттер и сеттер. Затем (перед созданием инстанса адаптера) проходите по всей коллекции и для каждого ее элемента устанавливаете соответствующий идентификатор вызовом `YourItem.setImageId(R.id.your_image).`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47466/discussion-between-inkognito-and-post-zeew).